# how to call stored procedure using spring and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, stored-procedures, orm

I get an error message as `java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException` and Invalid column name. Can you help me why am i getting this error.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried that gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following the recommendation of the documentation:

> #### [16.2.2.1. Rules/limitations for using stored procedures](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures)
>
> You cannot use stored procedures with
>   Hibernate unless you follow some
>   procedure/function rules. If they do
>   not follow those rules they are not
>   usable with Hibernate. If you still
>   want to use these procedures you have
>   to execute them via
>   `session.connection()`. The rules are
>   different for each database, since
>   database vendors have different stored
>   procedure semantics/syntax.
>
> Stored procedure queries cannot be
>   paged with
>   `setFirstResult()/setMaxResults()`.
>
> The recommended call form is standard
>   SQL92: `{ ? = call
>   functionName(<parameters>) }` or `{ ? =
>   call procedureName(<parameters>}`.
>   Native call syntax is not supported.
>
> For **Oracle** the following rules apply:
>
> - A function must return a result set. The first parameter of a
>     procedure must be an OUT that returns
>     a result set. This is done by using a
>     `SYS_REFCURSOR` type in Oracle 9 or 10.
>     In Oracle you need to define a `REF
>     CURSOR` type. See Oracle literature for
>     further information.
>
> For Sybase or MS SQL server the
>   following rules apply:
>
> - The procedure must return a result set. Note that since these
>     servers can return multiple result
>     sets and update counts, Hibernate will
>     iterate the results and take the first
>     result that is a result set as its
>     return value. Everything else will be
>     discarded.
> - If you can enable `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your procedure it will probably be
>     more efficient, but this is not a
>     requirement.

Once your code will be aligned with the rules, if you still get an error, please provide the full error message.